# Calculating Durations in Power Bi

Tags: time, powerbi, dax, duration

I've received a CSV file from a client to import into Power Bi for analytics. It's a list of dates, agents, and then columns of total & average call/talk/hold times, all in durations. I've imported it with Power Query and converted to Duration but can't get PBi to add/average out over the weeks/months per agent. What am I missing?

| DATE | AGENT | HANDLE TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/23 | Bob | 0:03:55 |
| 1/3/23 | Sam | 0:19:03 |
| 1/4/23 | Bob | 0:05:01 |

.....

Comment: Next time please use Google prior to engaging other people to help you.

Comment: I did, it took a while to figure out the proper query to get the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

PowerQuery has the **Duration** data type, but DAX hasn't. Instead, you have (fractions of) days that you can use for aggregations.

[image]

Multiply the result with 24 * 60 *60 to get seconds and then convert it back to a time-like format.